# Redirecting webhook via PHP to VB.Net

Tags: php, vb.net, webhooks

I need to receive a webhook at one location (r1) and resend it to another on a different port (r2).

I have a php script at the r1 which I don't think it completely correct as I want to retain the original headers and pass them on, rather than create new ones. However, as a start my PHP is like this:

```
<?php
    $raw_payload = file_get_contents('php://input',true);
    $payload = json_decode($raw_payload, true);
    $myVariable=print_r($payload, TRUE);
    if (is_array($payload)) {
        $fh = fopen("log.txt", "a+");
        if ($fh) {
            fwrite($fh, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()).PHP_EOL);
            fwrite($fh, $raw_payload.PHP_EOL);
            fclose($fh);
                    } else {
            echo("Unable to open file!");
        }
        $fh = fopen("jsondata.txt", "a+");
        if ($fh) {
            fwrite($fh, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()).PHP_EOL);
            fwrite($fh, $myVariable.PHP_EOL);
            fclose($fh);
                    } else {
            echo("Unable to open file!");
        }

$url = "http://my.static.ip.address:1234";
$meta = ["received" => time(),"status" => "new", "agent" => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']];
$options = ["http" => [
    "method" => "POST",
    "header" => ["Content-Type: application/json"],
    "content" =>  json_encode(["data" => $payload, "meta" => $meta])
    ]
    ];
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    } else {
        echo("Invalid payload!");
    }
?>
```

This certainly does something, as the TCP listener at r2 is triggered. However, it doesn't read anything from the stream:

```
    Sub Main()
        ' Set the port number
        Dim port As Integer = 1234
        ' Create a TcpListener
        Dim listener As TcpListener = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port)
        ' Start listening for incoming connections
        listener.Start()
        Console.WriteLine("Webhook receiver started. Listening on port " & port)
        Try
            While True
                ' Accept the connection when a client connects
                Dim client As TcpClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient()

                ' Process the incoming data
                Dim data As String = ReadDataFromClient(client)

                ' Print the received data to the console
                Console.WriteLine(Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss ") + "Received data: " + data.ToString)

                ' Close the client connection
                client.Close()
            End While
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
        Finally
            ' Stop listening for incoming connections when the loop exits
            listener.Stop()
        End Try
    End Sub
    Private Function ReadDataFromClient(client As TcpClient) As String

        Dim data As String = ""
        Dim buffer(1024) As Byte
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        Debug.Print("Receiving data")
        ' Read the data from the client
        Dim bytesRead As Integer
        While (bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0
            data += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            Debug.Print("Receiving data")
            Beep()
            Debug.Print(data)

        End While

        Return data
    End Function
```

`ReadDataFromClient` is triggered, but there's nothing in `data` as the buffer appears to be zero length.

The set up is that we have a website that receives the webhook at r1, this is then redirected to our static IP address at r2 on port 1234 where the router's port mapping then redirects that to a given internal server that will process the webhook.

I've tested the redirection by sending it to webhook.site and that receives the full payload, so I'm happy the basic premise of the redirection is working.

So, the questions I have from this are:

1. How do I pass the original headers received at r1 onto r2?
2. Why isn't the stream being read properly at r2, and what do I need to do to correct it please?

Edit: Additional info - I tried with with an http listener on port 1234 and that never received anything, so I think sticking with the tcp listener is the best option for us.

Edit 2:
Tried to interpret advice given below, and altered the PHP to:

```
$originalHeaders = getallheaders();

//$url = "http://my.static.ip.address:1234";
$url="https://webhook.site/my-webhook-url";
$meta = ["received" => time(),"status" => "new", "agent" => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']];
$options = ["http" => [
    "method" => "POST",
    "header" => $originalHeaders,
    "content" =>  json_encode(["data" => $payload, "meta" => $meta])
    ]
    ];

    $myVariable=print_r($originalHeaders, TRUE);
        $fh = fopen("log.txt", "a+");
        if ($fh) {
            fwrite($fh, date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()).PHP_EOL);
            fwrite($fh, $myVariable.PHP_EOL);
            fclose($fh);
                    } else {
            echo("Unable to open file!");
        }

$context = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Tried the merge with the headers and that wouldn't send so tried just copying them all and that doesn't send either. webhook.site receives nothing.

There are just 4 particular headers I need to transfer so is there a way I can just add those four to the original code?

Comment: Any reason to use php for this rather than a dedicated reverse proxy?

Comment: I did a lot of reading on that, but as I'm unfamiliar with it, and /etc/nginx/sites-available/ doesn't exist on the host, I gave up! :-) It was also trying to get my head round receiving via https and redirecting to http.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code on r2 that need to be addressed.

Passing Original Headers:
To pass the original headers from the incoming request at r1 to r2, you should modify your PHP script on r1 to include these headers in the POST request. You can do this by capturing the headers from the incoming request and then adding them to the $options array before sending the request. Here's how you can modify the PHP script on r1:

php

```
$originalHeaders = getallheaders();

$options["http"]["header"] = array_merge($options["http"]["header"], $originalHeaders);

$context = stream_context_create($options);

$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

This code will merge the original headers received at r1 with the headers required for the POST request.

Reading Data on r2:
In your VB.NET code on r2, you are using a TcpListener to listen for incoming data. However, it seems like you're expecting an HTTP POST request with headers and a body, which is more commonly handled using an HTTP listener (e.g., HttpListener in .NET).

If you still want to use TcpListener, you'll need to handle the HTTP request parsing manually, which can be quite complex. It's usually easier to work with an HTTP listener when dealing with HTTP requests.

Here's a simplified example of using HttpListener in VB.NET to listen for incoming requests on port 1234:

vb.net

```
Sub Main()
    Dim prefix As String = "http://*:1234/"
    Dim listener As New HttpListener()
    listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix)
    listener.Start()

    Console.WriteLine("Webhook receiver started. Listening on port 1234")

    Try
        While True
            Dim context As HttpListenerContext = listener.GetContext()
            Dim request As HttpListenerRequest = context.Request
            Dim response As HttpListenerResponse = context.Response

            ' Read headers and body from the request
            Dim headers As WebHeaderCollection = request.Headers
            Dim body As String = New StreamReader(request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()

            ' Process the headers and body as needed
            Console.WriteLine("Received headers:")
            For Each key As String In headers.AllKeys
                Console.WriteLine(key & ": " & headers(key))
            Next
            Console.WriteLine("Received body: " & body)

            ' Close the response
            response.Close()
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
    Finally
        listener.Stop()
    End Try
End Sub
```

This code listens for incoming HTTP requests on port 1234, reads the headers and body, and then processes them.

Note that working with raw TCP sockets for handling HTTP requests can be complex and error-prone. Using an HTTP listener is a more robust and standard approach for handling HTTP requests in .NET.

Comment: Thanks @valantis. I have a few issues with this. When I merge headers, it doesn't send. I'm wondering if i can just pick out the ones I need (certain security ones) and just add those...? If I ignore the header issues and go with the original php, the http listener doesn't detect anything. I mentioned this in the original post. the TCP listener is triggered when I post the webhook but the tcp listener does nothing.